# Regex expression gives StackOverflow error when matching large SOQL queries

Tags: apex, soql, validation, regular-expressions

For the purpose of query syntax validation, I've made the following regex expression:

```
String SOQL_QUERY_REGEX = '(?is)((?:SELECT[\\s]+[a-z0-9_]+[\\s]*(?:\\(.*?\\))?.*?[\\s]*(?:,(?:(?:[a-z0-9_\\s]+)|(?:[\\s]*.*?\\(.*?\\)[\\s]*.*?)))*)' + 
                          '(?:FROM .*?)' + 
                          '(?:(?:WHERE(?:(?:[^()]*?)|(?:.*?\\(.*?\\)[\\s]*)))(?:AND(?:(?:[^()]*?)|(?:.*?\\(.*?\\)[\\s]*)))*)?)' + 
                          '(?:LIMIT .*?)?' + 
                          '((?:OFFSET .*?)?' + 
                          '(?:FOR .*?)?' + 
                          '(?:UPDATE .*?)?)';
```

This will match with any valid SOQL query not containing `TYPEOF` operator. However, when I try it on large enough queries, I get a SO error. Here's an example of the query that is throwing the error: https://pastebin.com/raw/e3iJt8j0

The complete function I use to check syntax is:

```
    public static Boolean isValidQuery(String query) {
        if(query == null || query == '') { // null check
            return false; 
        }

        Pattern p;
        Matcher m;

        p = Pattern.compile(SOQL_QUERY_REGEX);

        m = p.matcher(query.trim());
        String newQuery;
        if(m.matches()) {
            newQuery = m.group(1) + ' LIMIT 0'; // group(1) is for everything before LIMIT while group(2) is for everything after
            if(m.group(2) != null) {
                newQuery += ' ' + m.group(2);
            }
        }
        else {
            // invalid syntax
            System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Invalid query syntax. Please review your query.');
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Is there a way I can optimize this query?

Comment: Can you explain why you're trying to validate SOQL queries in the first place? If you're allowing your users to run their own queries...why (doing so is a very serious security risk)? My first thought on how to handle this would be to stick the query in a try-catch and let invalid queries fail (you'd take care of reporting the error in the catch block).

Comment: Where's the risk if all I'm doing is just adding a LIMIT 0 and calling Database.query? I can't just run it because it may exceed limits otherwise. Also, blindly appending a LIMIT 0 to a query without checking to see the structure isn't a good idea. That's why the regex. Besides validation it also captures the various groups so that I end up appending LIMIT 0 correctly.

Comment: The risk is called SOQL injection, it's similar to SQL injection vulnerabilities on other platforms, and Salesforce [has a brief write-up on it here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm). The severity of the risk depends on what else you do with the results of the query.

Comment: Your comment also makes me feel like there is a lot of important information that you have left out here (nowhere in your question did you mention anything about adding `LIMIT 0` to queries, for example). This is quickly getting into X-Y problem territory. Validating SOQL queries is your attempted solution, what is the actual problem that you're trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: I've built a framework for running n arbitrary batch jobs in sequence without the need to use the Queueable interface. I am making the entire system configurable, meaning I have no information about the query until the user provides it to me at runtime. I need to make sure that I'm executing a valid query for the purpose of graceful error handling. Hence the LIMIT 0. Of course going into more detail involves divulging sensitive company information... thanks for understanding :)